# How many points does a thief score when placed on a tile with a crossing completing multiple roads?

Tags: carcassonne

I was a little worried that my theoretical [maximum Carcassonne score of 338 points](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7375/maximum-attainable-points-for-a-single-player-in-a-two-player-game-of-carcassonn) might be in error if it was possible to score multiple completed roads during the same turn.

The [rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_48_gameRules.pdf) say you place Thieves on a road segment:

[image: Road Segment]

> The player who has a thief on a completed road scores one point for each tile in the completed road (count the number of tiles; separate segments on a tile count just once).

**How many points can a Thief placed on this Road Tile score?**

[image: Quad Tile Thief]

Am I correct in believing that you have to choose a segment to one side of a crossing, and therefore you can only score 2 points here?

Comment: The other part of the rules that would've reassured you is the bit about only placing one follower per turn, and of course only scoring for what you put followers on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is my understanding of the rules. You could still score 8 points if you previously placed thieves on three of the road segments leading into the tile of course.

Comment: Yep, that's correct - you only score for the road you place your thief on, which would mean from the image in the question that the thief placed would score only 2 points, as all completed roads are only 2 tiles long.

Comment: Correct, but with the ghost expansion you could claim two of the roads.