# What are the differences between the 3 versions of Carcassonne?

Tags: carcassonne

I see this question was partially answered on B&CG for [scoring differences between the 3 versions of Carcassonne](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7/there-seem-to-be-several-different-scoring-systems-for-fields-cities-in-carcasso). Are there any other differences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides the scoring differences listed, there is also the "youngest player" goes first rule in 1st. Edition. For a list of all differences between editions, see this excellent [annotated rules list and FAQ](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/87531/carcassonne-standard-complete-annotated-rules) that covers the Basic Game and 11 expansions.